# rotate.schedule.interval.ms configuration does not work as expected for S3 sink connectors

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have setup a Kafka connector that consumes data from multiple topics and writes to S3.
The flush size is set to 200k and the rotate.schedule.interval.ms is set to 86400000ms(1 Day).
I expect data for each topic to be flushed once everyday regardless of it hitting flush size.
However data is only flushed when messages reach flush size.

Due to reasons, the connectors are kept paused for most of the day and is resumed for an hour each day, how does this impact rotate.schedule.interval.ms? Does the connector consider the pause time as well when it implements rotate.schedule.interval.ms functionality?

Comment: Also sub question, is there any way to manually flush all the data?

Comment: No, there is no way to manually flush. At least, maybe not without some JMX bean command to force the function to be called. In other words, the Connect API only has functions for the connector create/delete/pause, really, nothing specific to one connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pausing a connector will stop its internal Task classes. The config would be reloaded when those treads restart, meaning it should flush 24 hours after that (or when 200k events are read, whichever happens first).

Comment: We also have some connectors that run continuously but data reaches the s3 bucket two days after it's pushed to the connector topic. Not sure why rotate.schedule.interval.ms property does not work for that

Comment: Hard to say, I haven't looked at the source code in several years now, but you are welcome to step through and debug it https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3